# How do I pick 10 top and bottom values, but if there is a tie then I should use another columns values as a tie breaker

Tags: pandas, numpy

How can I pick top 10 and 10 bottom values of Limit column, but if there are duplicate values then I should use another columns values (Number column) highest value as a tie breaker.

So far I have this code:

```
df10 = df1[['Number', 'Limit']].sort_values('Limit')
top = df10['Limit'].nlargest(10) # to pick top val

if df10.head(10)['Limit'].duplicated():
    df10.append()['Number'].max()
```

I tried to approach this by setting up if command, but in this case I receive Value error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What about sorting by both `['Number', 'Limit']` then just taking the `head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
# Sort by the primary and secondary ways of determining placement
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['Limit' # add your secondary column here])

# Group by 'Limit'
# aggregate by taking the 'Number' that appears first based on sorting the two columns above
top_group = df1.groupby('Limit').agg({'Number':'first'})
# For the bottom 10, use the same sort but select the number appearing last
bottom_grp = df1.groupby('Limit').agg({'Number': 'last'})

top_10 = top_group['Number'].nlargest(10)
bot_10 = bottom_grp['Number'].nsmallest(10)
```

Comment: In this case I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'agg'.

Comment: There might be an error with your code prior to, or including, the groupby. Calling `groupby()` on your DataFrame should return a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object`, not a string.

Comment: You might be missing the closing parenthesis after the `'Limit'` argument of `groupby()`.